# MySql - switch value

Tags: mysql

I have the following scenario in mySql, is it possible to update the values with an update statement?

I'd like to set the value table 1.A to the value of 2.B when 1.A matches 2.C

```
Table1

columnA

Table2

columnB
columnC
```

I'm thinking of running the following - will it work?

```
Update Table1 SET Table1.columnA=Table2.columnB
WHERE Table1.columnA = Table2.columnC
```

Any help much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query -

```
Update
  Table1, Table2
SET
  Table1.columnA = Table2.columnB
WHERE
  Table1.columnA = Table2.columnC;
```

...or this query with JOIN clause -

```
Update Table1 JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.columnA = Table2.columnC  
SET
  Table1.columnA = Table2.columnB
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 
    JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.columnA = Table2.columnC
SET Table1.columnA=Table2.columnB
```